# Using font-face with Slidy / Pandoc?

Tags: css, embedded-fonts, pandoc

Is there a way to make an @font-face call in using Pandoc's Slidy?

At the beginning of my slidy.css stylesheet, I have a @font-face call in the tradtional format:

```
@font-face
{
font-family:'ChunkFiveRegular';
src:url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.svg#ChunkFiveRegular') format('svg');
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal;
}
```

But when I compile the Slidy file using Pandoc, I am get an error message:

```
pandoc: Could not determine mime type for `slidy/styles/fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.eot'
```

Can this be done?

Comment: What pandoc version are you using, and what command (options and arguments)?

Comment: @john-macfarlane I'm using pandoc 1.9.4.2 on OSX 10.7.4

The invocation I'm using is: 

`pandoc -s -t slidy --self-contained -V slidy-url=slidy --smart -o Desktop/index.html slidy-test.md`

Comment: Part of the problem is that pandoc doesn't know mime types for eot or woff extensions (which could easily be fixed).  If you removed those formats, does it work?